# FIXED! Eclipse Mars Console Closes As Soon As It Opens

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-mars

I am new to java and don't relay know much but I know this is not meant to happen. I don't know how to explain it(besides saying it disappears as soon as it opens)  so I made a video which you can find [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=97McsLCwybY&feature=youtu.be)

Now that you know what is happening I was wondering if you would know how to fix it. It was a lot worse before, I don't know what I did to make it better.

I am on windows the code I'm using is just this

`public class HelloWorld { //makes class
    public static void main(String[] args) { //Main part of program
        // Prints "Hello, World" to the terminal window.
        System.out.println("Hello, World");
    }
}`

It is the hello world of Java nothing much

I just need to fix this nothing else is broken.

Ok, i look at the comments and I would like to thank you to all who answered and big thanks to @Priyamal for telling me the issue all I did was delete the workspace folder and reopen eclipse and it worked! Thaks a lot!

Comment: Could you pop some of your code and a brief outline in the text as many video codecs do not work on my Linux distro and I am aware other users sometimes experience similar issues... :)

Comment: @Nick: welcome to StackOverflow. You'll find that you're much more successful at getting good answers if you provide code, symptoms, and what you're actually trying to achieve. Linking to external sites requires more work from people answering and also results in good questions disappearing later.

Comment: try removing your workspace folder, and start eclipse then import the projects into your new workspace.

Comment: @Priyamal You should post your comment as an answer. It worked for me, too.